# Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for ActorRef<UserParentActor$Create> was bound

Tags: java, playframework, akka, guice, akka-typed

I'm trying to create an actor in Java Play Framework (2.8.x) for webSocket. When my application runs, however, I get the error Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for ActorRef<UserParentActor$Create> was bound. (detailed error messages provided later in this post).

I'm sure the mistake is pretty basic, but I'm new to the whole actors thing and am having trouble figuring it out.

I am implemented same code as explained here :-
https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.8.x/play-java-websocket-example

> CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

```
1) [Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for ActorRef<UserParentActor$Create> was bound.

Requested by:
1  : HomeController.<init>(HomeController.java:47)
      \_ for 1st parameter
     at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:518)
      \_ for 122nd parameter HomeController_61
     at RoutesProvider$.bindingsFromConfiguration(BuiltinModule.scala:137):
Binding(class router.Routes to self)
      \_ installed by: Modules$OverrideModule -> GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4

Learn more:
  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/MISSING_IMPLEMENTATION

1 error

======================
Full classname legend:
======================
ActorRef:                           "akka.actor.typed.ActorRef"
GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4: "play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4"
HomeController:                     "com.alnt.identitymgmt.controller.HomeController"
Modules$OverrideModule:             "com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule"
RoutesProvider$:                    "play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$"
UserParentActor$Create:             "com.alnt.identityintel.util.actors.UserParentActor$Create"
========================
End of classname legend:
========================
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing the runtime injection. You can create `app/Module.java` by following the file in the example you referred. Roughlysomething like below should suffice:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Module extends AbstractModule implements AkkaGuiceSupport {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new TypeLiteral<ActorRef<UserParentActor.Create>>() {})
            .toProvider(UserParentActorProvider.class)
            .asEagerSingleton();
    }

//...

    @Singleton
    public static class UserParentActorProvider implements Provider<ActorRef<UserParentActor.Create>> {
        private final ActorSystem actorSystem;
        private final UserActor.Factory childFactory;
        private final Config config;

        @Inject
        public UserParentActorProvider(
            ActorSystem actorSystem, UserActor.Factory childFactory, Config config
        ) {
            this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
            this.childFactory = childFactory;
            this.config = config;
        }

        @Override
        public ActorRef<UserParentActor.Create> get() {
            return Adapter.spawn(
                actorSystem,
                UserParentActor.create(childFactory, config),
                "userParentActor");
        }
    }
}
```

More information can be found at playframework's doc on actor dependency injection: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AkkaTyped#Dependency-Injection